# Yii2: Error 404 after using Gii for a new database schema

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, database-schema, gii

I used **Gii code generator** to create a model and its CRUD for a table located in the non public schema but then the URL is not working: Error 404 not found.

I have a **PostgreSQL** database called **travels** with two schemas: **public** and **laboratory**. Everything works perfect using the public schema.

Now I need to use the laboratory schema that I created recently. So I created the model (a minor problem: autocomplete doesn't work for laboratory schema but the model is created anyway):

[image: Generating a model for laboratory.samples.]

Then I created the CRUD:

[image: Generating a CRUD for Samples.]

Then I try to see the results:

[image: I get this error: Not Found (#404). The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.]

It's my **common/config/main-local.php** file:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=travel',
            'username' => 'aaaa',
            'password' => 'bbbb',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: post your urlmanager config, do you have pretty url enabled?

Comment: You are creating models in app\models and the backend\models is that intended?

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, it works.

Comment: 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => true,
            'rules' => [

            ],
        ],

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I modified this file before and something was not right:

**/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/generators/crud/default/views**

The problem about model autocomplete is still there.

Answer (score 0):

[image: gii.js error 404 not found]

Copy the file gii.js from `vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/assets` to the directory where you throw the error for your case will vary.